# Access SQL: How to find duplicate records between dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

```
    SN            DATE
===========    =========
    111         1/1/2014
    222         2/1/2014
    333         3/1/2014
    111         4/1/2014
    222         5/1/2014
    333         6/1/2015
    222         7/1/2015
    111         8/1/2015
    333         9/1/2015
    111         10/1/2015
    111         11/1/2015
```

I have a table with 2 columns (`SN` and `DATE`). I would like to create a query that will find duplicate `SN` between `1/1/2014` and `31/12/2014`. I want to count duplicates and show each row that is a duplicate with `SN` and `DATE`.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where date between #2014-01-01# and #2014-12-31# and
      exists (select 1
              from table as t2
              where date between #2014-01-01# and #2014-12-31# and
                    t2.sn = t.sn and t2.date <> t.date
             );
```

However, this will not find an sn that has two records on the same date.  For that, you can do:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where t.sn in (select t2.sn
                from table as t2
                where date between #2014-01-01# and #2014-12-31#
                group by t2.sn
                having count(*) >= 2
               );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved the main part of my problem. First method works fine for me. I would like to know if its possible to add to this query extra parameters. How can I see how times one SN appears and how many days are between those dates.

Comment: @JohnP . . . That sounds like another question.  New questions should be asked as questions rather than in comments.  Sample data *and* desired results are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SN , Count(SN) AS Dup
FROM [TableName]
WHERE DATE BETWEEN #2014-01-01# AND #2014-12-31#
GROUP By SN
HAVING Count(SN) >1
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out those with no dupe:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where 
    ([Date] Between #2014-01-01# And #2014-12-31#)
    And SN Not In 
    (Select T.SN From YourTable As T
     Where T.[Date] Between #2014-01-01# And #2014-12-31#
     Group By T.SN
     Having Count(*) = 1)
```